# Compute the phase difference of sine wave at point in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, signal-processing

Different points in time have values modulated sinusoidally (like a signal arriving at each point).

[image: the points are represented by the red dots]

For the case as illustrated at the picture all points have the same value at the same time.

I have different cases were the wave is rotated along the vertical axis (Value), so that at the same time points have different values. The rotation angle is known.

[image: example of rotation]

Is there a way to compute the phase difference between the points after the rotation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what's the starting point of your problem. What is "given"? How much do you "rotate" the wave?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I made some additions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of your wave is $$V=A\sin(\omega t+\phi_p)$$
Here $V$ is the value, $t$ is the time, and $p$ is the position. The meaning of the angle of rotation does not make too much sense, since it depends on the units of position and time. What makes sense is the time where each of the points goes through a minimum (or maximum). What I mean by that, you know where you have a curve of constant value. You can write the first equation as $$V=A\sin(\omega(t+\Delta t_p))$$
And in your case $\Delta t_p$ is linear in $p$, so $$\Delta t_p=\frac{\Delta t_1-\Delta t_0}{p_1-p_0}p+\Delta t_0$$

Plugging it back into $\phi_p$, you get $$\phi_p=\omega\Delta t_p=\omega\frac{\Delta t_1-\Delta t_0}{p_1-p_0}p+\omega\Delta t_0$$

Then here $\frac{\Delta t_1-\Delta t_0}{p_1-p_0}$ is the slope of the constant level curve (tangent of the angle), and $\omega \Delta t_0$ is the phase of the point at the initial position.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Andrei for your detailed answer